# Npm install; Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart script

Tags: windows, node.js, angularjs, npm

May I know what is the problem here? I am clueless...
Thanks.

```
npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart: `npm install`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\
\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\bong\angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart: `npm install`
npm ERR! Exit status -1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\
\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\bong\angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bong\angular-phonecat\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing each dependencies seperately, It seems like a problem in package.json.